# How to turn digital time in to english name

Tags: java

I am working on a program but it seems to stall after asking the user the time. it is like it is skipping the if loops all together. Please show me what i am doing wrong.

```
package gettimename;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class getTimeName 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the hour ");
        int hours = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the minutes ");
        int minutes = in.nextInt();
    }


public static String getTimeName(int hours, int minutes)
{
    String time_name = "";

    String nums [] = {"Zero", "One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten",
        "Eleven","Twelve","Thirteen","Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen","Seventeen","Eighteen","Nineteen",
        "Twenty","Twenty one", "Twenty two", "Twenty three", "Twenty four", "Twenty five", "Twenty six", 
        "Twenty seven", "Twenty eight", "Twenty nine"};

        if (minutes == 0)
            time_name = nums[hours] + " o'clock ";

        else if (minutes == 1)
            time_name = "one minute past " + nums[hours];

        else if (minutes == 59)
            time_name = "one minute to " + nums[(hours % 12) + 1];

        else if (minutes == 15)
            time_name = "quarter past " + nums[hours];

        else if (minutes == 30)
            time_name = "half past " + nums[hours];

        else if (minutes == 45)
            time_name = "quarter to " + nums[(hours % 12) + 1];

        else if (minutes <= 30)
            time_name = nums[minutes] + "minutes past " + nums[hours];

        else if (minutes > 30)
            time_name = nums[60 - minutes] + "minutes to " + nums[(hours % 12) + 1];



    return time_name ;
}
}
```

Comment: Your program (starting in the `main` method) never calls any other method.  `getTime()` for example is never called.

Comment: Well.. you didn't call the method did you?

Answer (score 0):

`getTimeName()`. is never called in your program. Your program is doing what it should be doing, and not executing the if statements.

Assuming the rest of your code is correct, here is what your main method should look like;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the hour ");
    int hours = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the minutes ");
    int minutes = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println(getTimeName(hours, minutes));
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. I knew i was missing a step somewhere